# Magento CE custom attribute not rendering in the search grid

Tags: magento

We have stores on Magento CE 
Identical  code is running on both these domains (both are on different servers) 
One is rending custom attributes in the  search grid and other is not. Not sure why is it happening 
http://www.bahdos.com/diamond/round.html (not rendering custom attribute)
http://www.techtps.com/demo/gemdazzle/diamond/round.html/

magento cache is disabled
cache is  flushed
data is available in database
only custom attributes are not rendering in the grid like ( shape carat cut..)
Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched off "Flat file calogue" the custom attributes started showing in the search grid

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the values of your products are stored on the "global" scope and not only on a "storeview" scope.

You can check that by playing with the scope dropdown in the Product Edit page in the Backoffice or directly in database (scope_id in catalog_product_entity_* tables).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the attribute is enabled for searching.

Goto Manage attributes and check the attributes is enabled in searching for both

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are considered in search if they are set to required.
Also flat catalog should be switched on.

Comment: This means that you have not set few important attributes to required or you have not re-indexed.If flat catalog is on but flat tables not populated this will happen.If you keep flat catalog off your site will go too slow.